# How can I remove all whitespaces and linebreaks in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a string that looks like this...

> "
>   http://www.example.com/
>
> example.pdf"

I need to remove the whitespaces and linebreaks. How do I do this? My result should be

`"http://www.example.com/example.pdf"`

Comment: This is pretty basic _Learning Perl_ stuff.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use the [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) substitution operator:

```
$string =~ s/\s+//g;
```

The `\s` [character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes)  matches a whitespace character, the set `[\ \t\r\n\f]` and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) { s/\s+//g; print; }
```

?